# Urn Probability (need multiple ways)

Tags: probability

I need multiple ways to solve this question. Thank you!

**There are $A$ black balls, and $B$ white balls in an urn. You select balls one by one from this urn randomly without replacement. What is the probability that the $k$-th ball you selected is black? $(1\leq k \leq A+B)$, and $A,B$ are positive integers)**

Comment: Does it matter if it is the $k$-th or 1st ball? Think about that.

Comment: Im not sure what exactly the question is, my professor doesn speak much english. Im assuming the K-th ball

Comment: @Ashley: I edited and assumed you meant $A,B$ , instead of $a,b$ at the bottom. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct!

Comment: Ashley, what is the probability that the first ball is black? What about the second? What about the $k$-th?

Comment: I do not have any other information about this question :( I am sorry. I think thats why I am having such difficulty finding a way to solve it myself.

Comment: I am asking YOU to figure out the answers to my questions.

Comment: @user99680 Do you understand this problem the way its worded?

Comment: Im not really sure how to write it out since there are no numbers. Wouldnt it be B/ the sum of A plus B?

Comment: @Ashley, I think I do. I guess you have to consider all possible ways of removing balls at the 1st, 2nd,.., kth step, and figure out the probabilities at each, right?

Comment: How though if there are no numbers? @user99680

Comment: @Ashley: you need a general argument , where $A$, $B$ are any positive integers. The probability depends on how many balls you have left at the $k$-th step.

Comment: @user99680 What do you mean? Im still very confused. Im sorry

Comment: @Ashley: no problem, let me try to put it more clearly. Give me a few minutes; why don't you try some specific examples with small numbers for $A,B$ , say $A=2$, $B=3$ in the meantime?

Comment: So my teacher is wanting me to find the probability of the k-th ball being black, but how do I do this without any numbers? Is my answer going to be in numbers or an equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Hard Way:** You can calculate the probability directly. To motivate my calculation, let's first look at the case $k=3$. The probability 
that the 3rd ball is black depends on what happens in the first two draws. Taking all four cases into account we get
\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{P}(3^{\rm rd} \mbox{ ball is black})
&=& {B\over A+B}\,{B-1\over A+B-1}\,{A\over A+B-2}+ {B\over A+B}\,{A\over A+B-1}\,{A-1\over A+B-2}\\
&+& {A\over A+B}\,{B\over A+B-1}\,{A-1\over A+B-2}+ {A\over A+B}\,{A-1\over A+B-1}\,{A-2\over A+B-2}\end{eqnarray*}

Extending this argument we find that 
$$\mathbb{P}(k^{\rm th} \mbox{ ball is black})=\sum_b {k-1\choose b-1}{A^{\underline{b}} \, B^{\underline{k-b}} \over (A+B)^{\underline{k}}},\tag 1$$
where the underlined power is an alternative to the [Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol#Alternate_notations) for "falling factorial". The variable $b$ refers the number of black balls drawn.

By a well-known formula (see page 245 of Concrete Mathematics) we know that 
$$\sum_k {n\choose k}x^{\underline{k}}\,y^{\underline{n-k}}=(x+y)^{\underline{n}}.$$
It follows that 
\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_b {k-1\choose b-1} A^{\underline{b}} \, B^{\underline{k-b}} 
&=& A\sum_b {k-1\choose b-1} (A-1)^{\underline{b-1}} \, B^{\underline{k-b}}\\
&=& A(A+B-1)^{\underline{k-1}}\\
& =&{A\over A+B}(A+B)^{\underline{k}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Dividing this by $(A+B)^{\underline{k}}$ and using (1)  we get the result 
$$\mathbb{P}(k^{\rm th} \mbox{ ball is black})={A\over A+B}.$$

**Reference:** *Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science*, by Ronald Graham, Donald Knuth, and Oren Patashnik.

Comment: THANK YOU! So much. I needed a other way to solve it. Is there any other techniques I can use to solve the same problem?

Comment: @Ash00 I can't think of any other solutions at the moment. Of course, the argument by symmetry given by M.B. is far better!

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**: think about it as having aligned $A+B$ persons labeled $1, 2, \ldots, A+B$ in a straight line, and some guy with a bag of $A+B$ balls wherein $A$ are black and $B$ are white. This funny looking guy with a long beard wraps all of the balls into red paper and hands them out, one by one, to each person in the queue. After all have gotten their present they unwrap simultaneously. What is the probability that the $k$-th person got a black ball? Does it matter if you are the first or second person? Or the $k$-th?

Comment: The k-th person?

Comment: In the last sentence? Yes.

Comment: Yes I was answering your question. What is the next step?

Comment: Did you answer? What is your answer? Does it matter?

Comment: It matters if you are the k-th person

Comment: Nope, it does not!

Comment: But i thought you were finding the probability the k-th person got a black ball?

Comment: And I am telling you that it does not matter if you compute the probability for the first person, or any other person.

Comment: Okay, so what do I need to do next then? Just compute the probability of choosing a black ball is a first person, being B/A+B ??

Comment: Yes, and understand why that is true, of course.

Comment: Okay so then the second persons probability would be differenet..correct? How would I compute their probability of picking a black ball?

Comment: Please read what I have written.

Answer (score 2):

What M.B is saying is that the chance that "the first person gets a black ball" is *exactly the same as* "the $k$th person gets a black ball". As surprising as this sounds, it is completely true.

Imagine that after you draw each marble, you put it next to the previous ones, so you have a row of marbles. Once you've drawn the $k$th marble, you *don't* stop; you keep drawing until the urn is empty and you have a line of marbles $A+B$ long. (Drawing marbles after the $k$th can't possibly change the probability, right?) But you still know what the $k$th was, it's just the $k$th in the sequence.

But each possible sequence is *equally* likely! If you had numbered the balls, all you'd be doing is shuffling ${1, 2, 3, \ldots, A+B}$, and there's exactly one way to draw each permutation. It's exactly like shuffling a deck of cards. The chance that the Ace of Spades is at the top is exactly the same as the chance it's at the $41$st position. So the chance the first marble is black is equal to the chance the $k$th marble is black.

What is the chance of the first marble being black?